# What is size of image which android accept as background?

Tags: android, android-layout

Sometime when i try to add a background image in my android application project it not accept and sometime app crashes with some images while same app work well with other background images.This happen mostly with hd pics .So what the size of image i can use in my app without any problem.

Comment: Could you please post your code and the exception log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fixed image size that is allowed for background in android.
It depends on available memory on you device and your image size (resolution).

[from android documentation:](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

> For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with
>   an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384.
>   Loading this into memory uses 0.75MB rather than 12MB for the full
>   image (assuming a bitmap configuration of ARGB_8888).